# Vagrant box not talking to mysql on Mac through 127.0.0.1

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, mysql, vagrant

I'm running a vagrant box to host local sites. Importantly, the mysql server is running on the Mac, not the VM. When I've set the site configuration files to use `localhost` the site loads properly, but I'm unable to run `drush`(Drupal command line utility) from Mac side. If I change the site configuration to connect through 127.0.0.1 I can run `drush`, but then I end up with SQL error `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003]`.

I ran `dscacheutil -q host -a name localhost` from the Mac side and get the expected result:

```
name: localhost
ip_address: 127.0.0.1
```

On the VM side when I ran `hostname --ip-address` I get `127.0.0.1`

I guess this could be a Drupal issue, but it seems more like a VM/Mac issue, so I'm posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily a Drupal focused solution will work from: https://www.drupal.org/node/1428638

```
'host' => php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ? '127.0.0.1' : 'localhost',
```

In that post there's a reference to network socket versus Unix socket. I would love some reference or explanation on what that means. In the meantime, this is a usable site by site fix.